# Connectedness of fibers for flat, proper morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a flat proper morphism of noetherian schemes of finite type over a field. Assume that $Y$ is an integral scheme and the generic fiber of $f$ is irreducible of dimension $1$. Is it then true that every closed fiber of $f$ is connected?

Comment: Yes (you don't need dimension 1, only that the generic fiber is connected). This is EGA IV, Cor. 15.5.4.

Comment: I agree with abx's comment if by "connected" you mean "geometrically connected".

Comment: @abx, Moret-Bailly: Thank you very much.

Comment: If the field mentioned in the question is algebraically closed, then can we say that the generic fiber of $f$ is geometrically connected (assuming it is irreducible)? If not, is there any known additional assumption when this holds true?

Comment: @user45397 — geometrically connected means connected over $\bar{k}$. Since irreducible implies connected, you are fine.

Comment: @jmc: I think  for the generic fiber to be geometrically connected, I will need connectedness on the geometric generic point of $Y$, which is definitely not the same as the underlying field.

Comment: @user45397 — Ah, sorry. Of course, you are right.